# HardHat local network addresses balances

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

Is there a way to check the balances of the accounts generated when running `npx hardhat node`?

I mean printing them on the console like when you first boot up the network, not fetching them through js or any script

```
Accounts
========

WARNING: These accounts, and their private keys, are publicly known.
Any funds sent to them on Mainnet or any other live network WILL BE LOST.

Account #0: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80

Account #1: 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x59c6995e998f97a5a0044966f0945389dc9e86dae88c7a8412f4603b6b78690d

Account #2: 0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x5de4111afa1a4b94908f83103eb1f1706367c2e68ca870fc3fb9a804cdab365a

Account #3: 0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x7c852118294e51e653712a81e05800f419141751be58f605c371e15141b007a6

Account #4: 0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x47e179ec197488593b187f80a00eb0da91f1b9d0b13f8733639f19c30a34926a

Account #5: 0x9965507D1a55bcC2695C58ba16FB37d819B0A4dc (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x8b3a350cf5c34c9194ca85829a2df0ec3153be0318b5e2d3348e872092edffba

Account #6: 0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x92db14e403b83dfe3df233f83dfa3a0d7096f21ca9b0d6d6b8d88b2b4ec1564e

Account #7: 0x14dC79964da2C08b23698B3D3cc7Ca32193d9955 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x4bbbf85ce3377467afe5d46f804f221813b2bb87f24d81f60f1fcdbf7cbf4356

Account #8: 0x23618e81E3f5cdF7f54C3d65f7FBc0aBf5B21E8f (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0xdbda1821b80551c9d65939329250298aa3472ba22feea921c0cf5d620ea67b97

Account #9: 0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0x2a871d0798f97d79848a013d4936a73bf4cc922c825d33c1cf7073dff6d409c6

Account #10: 0xBcd4042DE499D14e55001CcbB24a551F3b954096 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0xf214f2b2cd398c806f84e317254e0f0b801d0643303237d97a22a48e01628897

WARNING: These accounts, and their private keys, are publicly known.
Any funds sent to them on Mainnet or any other live network WILL BE LOST.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardhat config defines the `accounts` [task](https://hardhat.org/getting-started#running-tasks) by default. It only prints the addresses but you can modify it to retrieve and print the balances as well:

*hardhat.config.js*

```
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
    const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const provider = hre.ethers.provider;

    for (const account of accounts) {
        console.log(
            "%s (%i ETH)",
            account.address,
            hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(
                // getBalance returns wei amount, format to ETH amount
                await provider.getBalance(account.address)
            )
        );
    }
});
```

Output of `npx hardhat accounts`

```
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 (10000 ETH)
0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8 (10000 ETH)
0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC (10000 ETH)
...
```

You can also use the `provider.getBalance()` function to retrieve an account balance during runtime of your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on a terminal here is the way.

run this code in the terminal to get console access of hardhat so that you can access and talk to the local blockchain

```
npx hardhat console --network localhost
```

Now run this js code in the shell of hardhat

```
// get all the accounts on our loach hardHat chain
const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

// get all the balance of the first account, as we have 20 accounts provided by default we can go till 19 (0-19)
account_balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(accounts[0].address)
BigNumber { value: "9999999824474125000000" }


// converting the balance in Ether form
ether_balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(account_balance.toString())
'9999.999824474125'
```